# Save session in database using codeigniter

Tags: session, codeigniter

I have an application made ​​by CodeIgniter.

I have made so that it can be installed. When you come to the site I check if database.php available. If it does not exist so I create database.php and my database and tables.

It works fine, but now I have a problem.

I want to save the sessions in the database. (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

To do that I had to change my config.php.

```
$ config ['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$ config ['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$ config ['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$ config ['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$ config ['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$ config ['sess_table_name'] = 'Session';
$ config ['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$ config ['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$ config ['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

The problem I have is that since I do not have a database.php from the start, I get an error message when I want to install the application. Error message I get is that database.php missing.

How can I solve this? I have tried using this: $ this-> config-> set_item ('sess_use_database', TRUE);

It has not worked. So any advice is welcome.

Comment: Well, you don't have a "database.php" from the start? how do you expect codeigniter to "know" which database use to store your session information? Or am i misinterpreting something?

Answer (score 0):

You must connect your database (Mysql or MSSQL ...), please modified application/config/databases.php and follow user guide

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Before using session via database, please add session encryption key to your application/config/config.php, open the file and set:`$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";`

Please referrer the following URL to read "Session Data to a Database" section:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind storing your session variables in the cookie

just set `$config ['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;` to FALSE.

Since it appears you are not using a database, there is no downside.

There could be one if you decide to implement a DB and then base your queries in the user data. Which would lead to huge security holes in your application.